# Machine Learning, Clustering IN Elbow method

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

`from sklearn.cluster import KMeans wcss = [] for i in range(1, 11): kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, init = 'k-means++', random_state = 42) kmeans.fit(X) wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)`

shows error"["shows error"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOvy0.png)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
"

I tried to  to fit the kmeans model and appending wcss values in the wcss list ..but it shows the above error.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: with X initialized as `np.random.random(size=(200, 4))` works fine, please care to provide [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).